# Yii Dropdown List Empty Value as Default

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a dropdownlist in my _form model and I want to add a empty value (which I want as default). I have the following:

In _form:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'country_id'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',Country::items(),array('empty' => '--Select a country--')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'country_id'); ?>
```

In Model Country:

```
public static function items()
{
    return CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAllBySql(
                        'SELECT * from country'), 
                        'id', 'name');
}
```

Even my empty option is in the first row in dropdownlist, the 1st country in list shows as default.

I tried:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',
    Country::items(),array('empty'=>'--Select a country--',
                           'options'=>
                             array(
                               '3'=>array('selected'=>'selected')
                                 )
     )); 
?>
```

In this way I can choose the default option, but cant set it to empty value, just countries that came from model:items.

Any idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you sure that `country_id` property of your model is not set to anything when you print the dropdown list? The following works for me if `$model` instance is created using `new Country()` operator but not by populating properties from database:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'country_id',
    Country::items(),
    array(
        'empty'=>'--Select a country--')
    );
?>
```

Comment: country_id is not setting anything. This $model is another model that has country_id as a FK. 'country' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country', 'country_id'), and in country model: 'team'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Team','country_id') ... I have this same code in another apps, and it works.. just in thsi case, the same code.. dont works...

Comment: Sorry, my BIG mistake, i set in database that country_id in tbl_team has a default value = 1...

Answer (score 12):

Read [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail). There is 'prompt' parameter.

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',Country::items(), array(
        'prompt' => '--Select a country--'
    ));
?>
```

See more details here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11195-how-to-edit-the-default-option-in-dropdownlist/

Answer (score 1):

You always can do something like array_merge in your `items` method

```
public static function items()
{
return array_merge(array(''=>'--Select a country--'), CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAllBySql(
                            'SELECT * from country'), 
                            'id', 'name'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe youre looking for:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',Country::items(),array('prompt'=>''));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use yiibooster maybe this will help

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
            $model,
            'kode_cuti_sub2',
            array(
                'empty'=>'--Select a country--',
                'widgetOptions' => array(
                    'data' => array('Something ...', 'Pilih Jenis Cuti'=>Chtml::listData(Cuti::model()->cuti_sub2(),'kode','jenis_cuti')),
                    'options' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Pilih NIP Pegawai',
                        'width' => '100%',
                    ),
                ),
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                ),
            )
        ); ?>
```

in my case it's worked